# How to prove if a binary number is divisible by 3?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, binary

I want to know how can I prove if a binary number is divisible by 3?
I've found the answer for a decimal num but I need binary form.
(using modular arithmetic a∣b)

Comment: The notation $a|b$ has nothing to do with modular arithmetic. What do you mean?

Comment: @GitGud I think I agree with your point, but it is a little unfair to say it has *nothing* to do with it.  For example I have seen as a definition $a|b \iff a \equiv 0 \mod b$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine whether or not a binary number is divisible by $3$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979274/determine-whether-or-not-a-binary-number-is-divisible-by-3)

Comment: @barakmanos Can u explain the equation please?!

Comment: @3ngineer: What equation?

Comment: @barakmanos the one in this page http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979274/determine-whether-or-not-a-binary-number-is-divisible-by-3

Comment: @3ngineer: You can write a comment under that answer, and ask the author directly.

Comment: I already know that I should ask the author, but I can't cause of my reputation :| @barakmanos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To *prove* that a certain number is divisible by $3$, the most convincing strategy is to show a number that when multiplied by $3$ yields the target number.

As for a digit-based *test* for divisibility by $3$:

Count the number of `1` bits in *even* posititions (that is, ones, fours, sixteens, and so forth). Subtract the number of `1` bits in *odd* positions (that is, twos, eights, thirty-twos, and so forth). The result of the subtraction is divisible by $3$ if and only if the original number was.

Comment: thanks for your answer:) I already knew that, do u know if there's any way to prove using modular arithmetic

Comment: @3ngineer: I don't understand what it is you're asking, then.

Comment: Indeed, this is the standard test for divisibility by `11` in *all* number bases, where `11` is interpreted in the base in question. To base $2$, it gives divisibility by $3$, to base $10$ it gives divisibility by $11$, to base $16$ it gives divisibility by $17$. Best of all, to base $1$ it gives divisibility by $2$.

Comment: I've found this answer but i can't get it! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979274/determine-whether-or-not-a-binary-number-is-divisible-by-3

Comment: @Martin: It is specific for base two that the instruction can be as simple as "count the ones". In other bases you need to say to "add the digits" at alternating positions.

Comment: Yes, that's quite right. Adding and counting are only equivalent for bases $1$ and $2$.

Comment: I mean what if the num was long so i can't count the 1s?!